# css reflect troubles - reflecting the wrong part of an image

Tags: html, css, reflection, image

I have an image where I want to reflect below the bottom of the image using CSS in Chrome.
The image is inside a div and I have constrained the max-height and max-width of the image.

The reflected image is showing the top of the image instead of the bottom of the image.

Here is a link to a working example: [go](http://jsfiddle.net/TYfh9/)

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
    img{   
      -webkit-box-reflect: below 0px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(50%, transparent), to(rgba(255,255,255,0.2)));
      max-height:315px;max-width: 220px;
    }
    div{overflow:hidden;height:275px;border:1px solid green}</style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div>
     <img src="http://www.oracledigital.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/google-penguin-update.png" />
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The `<div>` constrains where the reflected image goes. with a set `height` in pixels and `overflow:hidden` it has nowhere to go, so the reflected image moves up to fit in. Remove the 
HTML `<div>` tags temporarily to see what I mean. (Or remove `overflow:hidden`).

Is this more what you wanted?

http://jsfiddle.net/8a8NU/

I've simply removed `overflow:hidden` and changed the `color-stop` to 80%.

Comment: the div height is not actually causing the problem. If you remove the max-height and max-width on the img, then the image reflects properly.

Comment: I need the overflow:hidden. Do you have a solution with this?

Comment: In all honesty I don't know... I've noticed if you remove the `height/width` or `max-height/max-width` of the image it works as you require, but I'm guessing you need that too. Maybe if you resized the image beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/TYfh9/3/

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TYfh9/3/)

```
<div> 
  <img src="http://www.oracledigital.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/google-penguin-update.png" class="reflectBelow" />
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.reflectBelow  { 
  -webkit-box-reflect: below 0
    -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), to(white)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reduce size of the image.

[see demo](http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8o/1/image%20reflection%20in%20chrome)

Comment: but you removed the overflow:hidden, which is a requirement